# Databricks DBFS File Browser not showing some DBFS root locations

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a fresh Azure Databricks instance that I'm doing some experimenting on. Per the Databricks documentation, I [activated the DBFS File Browser](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/workspace/dbfs-browser.html) in the Admin Console.

However, when browsing the DBFS root location, only `FileStore`, `mnt` and `user` folders are showing (see below). Reading [this Databricks doc](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#dbfs-root-1), I expected to also see `databricks-datasets`, `databricks-results` and `databricks/init`, but these are not showing in the GUI.

[image: DBFS File Browser]

However, I am able to access e.g. `databricks-datasets` programatically through a notebook command:

[image: access databricks-datasets]

Does anyone know what is going on here? At first I thought it may be different since it's an instance of Azure Databricks, but the [Azure Databricks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system) is exactly the same and suggests I should be able to see the same root folders.

Why can I not see some DBFS root folders in the DBFS File Browser GUI, even though I can programatically access them?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. There is no folder/file appearing in the UI of Databricks at the following location: `dbfs/FileStore/` even after I do an upload. But it does appear in the notebook when I run `dbutils.fs.ls("/FileStore/")`.

However, the folders and files can be found in the UI at the following location: `/FileStore/`